# PHP: Use of static function

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, static, public

i've one stupid question.
I keep trying to write my framework, but ... i miss something.
I have one base class Base.class.php, with some functions. 
When, i write another class SubBase.class.php, who extends Base, i trying to set one variable , who must use in Base class, in one static function (maybe).
Something like that

```
class Base { 
 public $vars;
 public function GetA() { 
  return $this->vars;
 }
}


public SubBase extends Base { 
 public function __construct() { 
  $this->vars = array();
 }
}
```

But, i missing something ... 
In role, my SubBase is subpage from my web, Base is printHTML class. I trying to set a title to my web, with my Base class, who set $this->vars in my SubBase class o.O
Please, tell me if i'm wrong, and let me know how to write this.
I wonna just write

```
<title> <?php echo Base::GetTitle(); ?> </title>
```

and show in.

Comment: I see no static functions anywhere in your code.

Comment: What version of PHP do you use? Versions prior to PHP 5.3 does not support late static binding (LSB).

Comment: Where is `GetTitle()` in your class?

Comment: Why last comments are missing? With my?  Evan Mulawski:,BoltClock: That's just example, this's not a problem. alexn: 5.3.4 .That's work http://pastebin.com/x19X7Hhb ... but i don't like it.

Comment: It would help us help you if you posted the actual code you were working with.

Comment: That's my base class http://pastebin.com/ZeeYiZbX , and this is my subclass http://pastebin.com/bkqEmUd7 .I trying to set $this->config from my TPLHome class, and show in my index.php with TPLBase::getMeta(); ,but don't work. I hope that's helpful, sorry, but i can't asking help very well :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should take a look at static properties and methods: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

To accomplish what you want, you can try the following:

```
class Base { 

   //--------------------------------
   // Declare static property
   public static $title = '';

   //--------------------------------
   // Declare static method
   public static function GetTitle() { 
      return self::$title;
   }
}

public SubBase extends Base { 

   //--------------------------------
   // Construct which overwrites
   // Base::$title
   public function __construct($newTitle){
      self::$title = $newTitle;
   }
}

//--------------------------------
// Instantiate your SubBase object
$subPage = new SubBase($newTitle = 'Welcome to my sub page');

//--------------------------------
// And in your HTML, use
<title> <?php echo SubBase::GetTitle(); ?> </title>
```

Note, that I used SubBase::GetTitle(); and not Base::GetTitle();  If you use Base::GetTitle(), you're output will be blank because you're using the value given at the Base Class. In my example, its:

```
public static $title = '';
```

However, when you instantiate your SubBase class, you provide a "$newTitle" parameter, which then overrides the blank value.

Ideally, this should work. Still, I recommend you learn more about the use of static properties and methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wonna this, i can't use my sub class (SubBase), because every page is new sub class (SubBase2, SubBase3) and every extends Base class. That's why i can't use this, but a lot of thanks OV Web Solutions. I reading php manual few time, but i can't find nothing helpful.

Comment: OV Web Solutions that's the problem, but a can't find a solution ... i think ... that static function is not a best solution, but i hope there one of all ...